# Problem with Error message: could not find function "guides_train"

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggtern

after updating R I am confronted with the issue, that the message arises "Error: could not find function 'guides_train'.

In fact all ggplot diagrams work - only if I do a ternary plot, using the package ggtern, then all diagrams I prepared before don't work any more.

I have also tried to use standard example codes still there I get the same error.

https://www.r-bloggers.com/2017/07/version-2-2-1-released/

```r
library(ggtern)
library(ggalt)     #<<< Install this if it isn't installed!
data("Fragments")
base = ggtern(Fragments,aes(Qm,Qp,Rf+M,fill=GrainSize,shape=GrainSize)) + 
  theme_bw() + 
  theme_legend_position('tr') + 
  geom_encircle(alpha=0.5,size=1) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(title    = "Example Plot",
       subtitle = "using geom_encircle")
print(base)
```

I figured out that "guides_train" is changed in the current ggplot2 Version 3.5.0, https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/news/index.html. When I look at the download data of the latest ggtern version, https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/ggtern/index.html, it refers to ggplot2 ≥ 3.4.0.

I am not sure then if changes with ggplot2 3.5.0 are really considered, and I don't know if I had to consider anything else. I have tried to install older ggplot2, but without success.

I am very grateful for hints.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

R is not the culprit. In R 4.3.2, I tried to run the code. Before updating **ggplot2**, it worked (version 3.4.4). After installing the newest version of **ggplot2** (3.5.0), I got the same error message as you did. Your suspicion is correct, the **ggplot2** update broke the functionality of `guide_train()`, and **ggtern** devs have not had enough time to adress this. Maybe your best option is to revert back to **ggplot2** 3.4.4.. To do this, unload ggplot2 if it currently loaded. For example by restarting R. Then:

```r
require(devtools)
install_version("ggplot2", version = "3.4.4", repos = "http://cran.us.r-project.org")
```

Usually, I would also recommend filing a bug report at **ggtern**s website, so devs get notified of the problem. But their website is unavailable unfortunately.

Another fix involves fixing the source code of **ggtern** yourself, to accept the remodeled guide system of **ggplot2** 3.5.0.

Comment: Thank you for your feedback. Using your proposed code, I was able to revert ggplot2 back to 3.4.4.  Ggtern works fine again. I will try in the meanwhile to write to the developer of ggtern.